# Python - Keras: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d_19" (type Conv2D)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Just started into Python and trying this Convolutional Neural Network Code that i got. I have an error that i don't understand how to tackle this problem. Here are the Error and the screenshot of it. Anyone know how to fix this problem and what cause the problem ?

Here are the Model.

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3,
                            padding='valid', 
                            input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))  
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  
    model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3))  
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))  
      
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, 
                            padding='valid'))  
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3))  
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))  
      
    model.add(Flatten())  
    model.add(Dense(256))  
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(2))  
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))  

    return model
```

Here are the Error that i encountered

```
<ipython-input-38-2c04f3481c07> in main()
 14     x_train /= 255.0
 15     x_test /= 255.0
 16     model = create_model()
 17     model = compile_model(model)
 18 

<ipython-input-12-f222bdbd85f1> in create_model()
 14                             padding='valid'))  
 15     model.add(Activation('relu'))
 16     model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3))
 17     model.add(Activation('relu'))
 18     model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in_method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)

627     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
628     try:
629       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
630     finally:
631       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
 65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
 66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
 68     finally:
 69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
 2011   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
 2012     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
 2013     raise ValueError(e.message)
 2014 
 2015   return c_op
```

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "conv2d_19" (type Conv2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_19/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 3, 3, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_19/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64], [3,3,64,64].

Call arguments received:
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 1, 64), dtype=float32)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide full model definition and the shape of your train data? However I am guessing that there might be a problem with dimension ordering in your data.

By default, Convolution2D (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) expects the input to be in the format (samples, rows, cols, channels), which is "channels-last". Please confirm that your data is in NHWC format (samples, rows, cols, channels) rather than (samples, channels, rows, cols).

Comment: Hi Mr @PiotrGrzybowski , thanks for replying. yes i can provide the full model, i'll put the full model on the question. for the data that i used it's the same as the yf.download data.